Wrong observer list used when implementing Subject twice with Observer pattern
I have implemented a simple Observer pattern in c++ like this:
template<typename T>
class Observer {
private:
    virtual void notify(const T& data) = 0;
public:
    virtual ~Observer() = default;
};

template<typename T>
class Subject {
public:
    void subscribe(Observer<T> *observer);
    void unsubscribe(Observer<T> *observer);
    virtual ~Subject() = default;
protected:
    void notify(const T& data);
private:
    std::list<Observer<T>*> observers;
};

template<typename T>
void Subject<T>::subscribe(Observer<T> *observer) {
    this->observers.push_back(observer);
}

template<typename T>
void Subject<T>::unsubscribe(Observer<T> *observer) {
    this->observers.remove(observer);
}

template<typename T>
void Subject<T>::notify(const T& data) {
    for (const auto &observer: this->observers) {
        observer->notify(data);
    }
}

It defines two classes, Observer and Subject. The Subject stores a list of Observers and implements a notify method which notifies all Observers with some kind of data.
Now I implemented a Car class, which inherits subject twice, one for move "events" and one for steer "events":
class Car : public Subject<MoveData>, public Subject<SteerData> {
    ...
    void move() {
        const MoveData moveData{};
        this->Subject<MoveData>::notify(moveData);
    }

    void steer() {
        const SteerData steerData{};
        this->Subject<SteerData>::notify(steerData);
    }
    ...
}

If I now create a instance of my Car class and call the move function, it happens that the notify method of the Subject<MoveData> base class uses the observer list of the Subject<SteerData> base class, which causes segmentation faults.
My goal is that the notify function of the MoveData-Subject also uses the observers stored in the Subject<MoveData> base class, no matter how often I use the abstract Subject class as a base class.

How did you diagnose that "notify method of the Subject base class uses the observer list of the Subject base class"?

Work as expected here

A more modern approach is to no longer use virtual functions at all. C++ has std::function which is a great alternative and doesn't require you to define abstract baseclasses for each new type of observer you want to implment. Online demo : https://onlinegdb.com/Zy04AVXmQ.

Please provide [mcve]. Something what can be compiled and run - reproducing issue.

Your code has lost of missing parts wrong use of private, but after fixing that it seems to work correctly: https://godbolt.org/z/8YrdW639s

I accidently unsubscribed an subject while it was iterating over its observers which was causing the segmentation fault!
I tried to simplify my problem to post it on StackOverflow, which made the problem dissappear.

That is why providing MCVE is important. So it is clear that you are showing a code which actually contains the issue.
